# Do you need permission to use a well known first name in your company?

Tags: trademark, branding

I intend to produce a mobile/app/software. The specifics doesn't matter but let's say there is someone extremely famous in the *same field*. A comparison is creating an F1 app called "Michael F1". I intend to use only the first name but everyone understand who this refers to.

The person is dead. Could his descendants make some kind of claim because they own a brand or something?

Comment: How long has the person been dead? Is the well known person's name trademarked?

Comment: Names cannot be trademarked (In the U.S. that is).   If your brand is styled like the famous person, it could be a different matter.

Comment: The person is _not_ dead.

Comment: @hszmv "styled" is a bit vague. Can I mention his full name on the web page for example? I think not..

Comment: @arisalexis:  By "Styled" I mean that merely typing "Walt Disney" is not a violation of any copyright, however use of THE Walt Disney's signature (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walt_Disney#/media/File:Walt_Disney_1942_signature.svg) or the Disney Company's logo featuring the signature (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walt_Disney_Pictures#/media/File:Walt_Disney_Pictures_Logo_2011.svg) then you're crossing into IP issues.  I could write a fictional book about a guy who has the unfortunate name of Walt Disney or a clone of Walt.  But I can't use the real one's signature or company logo.

Comment: @hszmv thanks, that means that you can name a company Walt Comics just because it's only a first name right?

Comment: @arisalexis: Yes, so long as Disney does not own the comics, and the company does not print unauthorized comics about licensed Disney owned characters or meth dealers in the state of New Mexico.

Comment: @arisalexis: In fact, on the subject of comics, they hold a really bizarre one.  Both D.C. and Marvel have a character named Captain Marvel.  Because of some wacky legal situations, D.C.'s character is older by leaps and bounds, but Marvel can sue D.C.  if the title of any comics featuring that character include the words "Captain Marvel" while D.C. cannot sue Marvel for publishing a comic titled "Captain Marvel" (D.C. publishes the character under the title of "Shazam" and sue if it's used as a title on a Marvel comic... but the word has appeared in dialog in a marvel comic without issue.).